# Get N line from unzip -l

Tags: linux, awk, grep, unzip

I have a jar file, i need to execute the files in it in Linux.
So I need to get the result of the unzip -l command line by line.
I have managed to extract the files names with this command :

```
unzip -l package.jar | awk '{print $NF}' | grep com/tests/[A-Za-Z] | cut -d "/" -f3 ;
```

But i can't figure out how to obtain the file names one after another to execute them.
How can i do it please ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don’t understand the lame close vote.  Since when are shell programming questions  considered off-topic due to beiing non-programming questions?  **Shell programming is programming,** so this question definitely belongs here. It is not off-topic. *Bloody élitists!*

Comment: I code in Java usually and i can tell that shell scripting is at least as challenging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt, which also take into account Daddou's request to remove the .class extension:

```
unzip -l package.jar | \
awk -F'/' '/com\/tests\/[A-Za-z]/ {sub(/\.class/, "", $NF); print $NF}' | \
while read baseName
do
    echo "  $baseName"
done
```

Notes:

- The *awk* command also handles the tasks of *grep* and *cut*
- The *awk* command also handles the removal of the .class extension
- The result of the awk command is piped into the *while read...* command
- *baseName* represents the name of the class file, with the *.class* extension removed
- Now, you can do something with that $baseName

Answer (score 2):

If all you need the first row in a column, add a pipe and get the first line using `head -1`

So your one liner will look like :

`unzip -l package.jar | awk '{print $NF}' | grep com/tests/[A-Za-Z] | cut -d "/" -f3 |head -1;`

That will give you first line

now, club head and tail to get second line.

`unzip -l package.jar | awk '{print $NF}' | grep com/tests/[A-Za-Z] | cut -d "/" -f3 |head -2 | tail -1;`

to get second line.

But from scripting piont of view this is not a good approach. What you need is a loop as below:

```
for class in `unzip -l el-api.jar | awk '{print $NF}' | grep javax/el/[A-Za-Z] | cut -d "/" -f3`; do echo $class; done;
```

you can replace `echo $class` with whatever command you wish - and use `$class` to get the current class name.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Sorry if i was vague, this is what i exactly need.
This is what i have right now after i execute my command : 

    file1.class
    file2.class
    file3.class
    file4.class

This is what i want : 

file1.class   ONLY 
then file2.class ONLY ...  So i can execute them separately.

So basically i want to get the first line,then the second,the third until the end of the result set ... 
Your command hasn't worked for me sorry.

Comment: Thank you ringbearer, i managed to the same with sed , i'll accept your answer. But can i know why my approach is bad ?

Comment: @Daddou - thanks and good to see you got it. There are many ways to approach this issue using shell scripting. I gave you most generic that can be used in scenarios like yours - or at least what it appeared to be.

Comment: Since you're here :)  how can i suppress the .class extension please ? And do you have a good and clear reference site to write efficient scripts please ?  thanks a lot

Comment: I will give you hints - you can use sed to replace [A-Za-z].class with back reference \1 - or you could use grep and cut together or grep and awk together. But sed will be better. See if you can get a copy of 'Wicked Cool Shell Scripts'

Comment: I managed to do it also, thanks for the reference ring bearer